# How to fill 3/4" gap between tub and tile floor

Tags: bathroom, bathtub, trim, sealing, caulking

My house is 120 years old and there are very few level surfaces or right angles.

I just had the (alcove) tub and shower replaced. One end of the tub apron is nearly flush with the floor, but the other end has about 3/4" clearance.

Without ripping the floor up, how can I seal this gap to keep the subfloor under the tub dry?
[image: gap under tub]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a bead of silicone adhesive to attach a baseboard and then run a bead of caulk where it contacts the tub and another bead where it contacts the floor.  This will keep out most incidental drips and splashes.

The other option is to insert a backer board into the crack and install a curb tile.

Comment: Is it okay to use wood in something like this that will be exposed to water a lot?

Comment: No wood!!!! Mold, fungus, rot, etc.

Comment: @LeeSam I didn't think so, I ended up with a pvc quarter round and silicone caulk

Comment: Yes.  I was unclear.  PVC or composite.